# Output always returns undefined in saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a hard time in getting the data. I don't know where I went wrong.

Button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 10px;" onclick="save()">Save</button>
```

Data coming from:

```
//index is dynamic from another js
var hide = '<label><input type="radio" class="menuOptions" name="save' + index + '" id="access' + index + '" value="0" ' + (access == 0 ? 'checked' : (access == 3 ? 'disabled' : '')) + ' <?php isset($access) ? ($access == 1 ? "disabled" : "") : "disabled" ?>/>Hide</label>';

function save() {
    var a = [];

    for (var i = 0; i != data.length; i++) {
        a.push({
            'value': $('input[name="save' + i + '"]:checked').val()
        });
    }
    console.log(a)
}
```

Data: When I console.log(a)

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
 0: Object
    a: 2
    title: 'MyTitle'
    __proto__: Object
 1: Object
    a: 2
    title: 'AnotherTitle'
    __proto__: Object
```

So on and so forth.

Comment: What is undefined??? BTW, i don't understand what you mean in question's title, because `Output undefined always returns undefined`, seems logic after all

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Ok so, how do you output it??? Again, what returns `undefined`?`save()` method or what? If `save()` method, returns `a` as in Tushar's answer. If you are outputting `a` outside `save()` method, then ya, it is `undefined` outside `save()` scope. `var a = [];` you are defining `a` local to function wrapper scope  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: data looks mysterious. It is not obvious how it is being injected  into the scope or what it represents

Answer (score 4):

Because you haven't returned anything from function by default `undefined` is returned.

My primary guess is that `data` and checked checkboxes has no connection at all. So, when you loop using the `data.length`, there is no checked checkboxes, hence you might be getting `undefined`. Otherwise, you've got `[]` as output of `log`.

Anyway, I've also updated the `save()`.

```
function save() {
    var a = []; // Initialize array

    var checkedElements = $('input[name="save"]:checked'); // Get all save checked checkboxes

    for (var i = 0; i < checkedElements.length; i++) {
        a.push({
            value: checkedElements.eq(i).val() // Add value of checked checkboxes in array
        });
    }

    return a; // return array from function
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is coming from the radioboxes. When i change it still gives me undefined. I've updated my question.

Comment: @aldrin27 Can you please create jsfiddle.net demo. It'll be easier to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably becasuse the `data` is out of scope. If you try to log `data` in the function it will probably be undefined, and the loop has nothing to iterate over. Either pass the data to the funciton `save(data)` or make the data availible in the "above" scope